# How to decrypt excel file 2007 by POI 3.8 if it is protected by "Restrict Editing"

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In excel 2007, we can Protect Workbook by select "Protect Workbook" on menu and select "Protect Structures and Windows".

I have file with extension ".xlsm" and it is protected like the way above. I have password of this file and I need to  read it by POI 3.8 in java, how can I do that?

I used to use the class "Decryptor" to verify the password, but it useless.
Please help me, I have stucked in this for 3 days...

Comment: Check the character encoding you are using for the password.  If Excel is expecting plain ASCII or some MS encoding, then if you are giving it UTF-16 you will have problems.

Comment: [Decryptor](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html) is what you should be using. What happens when you try it?

Comment: When I use Decryptor, there are one exception:"Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream". The extension of this file is "xlsm" and I use POI 3.8. I tried to read a "xlsm" file that is not protected and it read normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this

1. Create a Excel Object
2. Open workbook
3. Unprotect with password ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect
4. Save file
5. Open in POI
6. Remake steps 1 to 4, but protect file

[]'s

Comment: Actually, I need to write a web application that allowed user import excel file. My customer have an excel file but it is protected.